# How can I use Local Notification in Zebble?

Tags: zebble, xamarin-zebble

I want to show notification in my app

I searched and found

http://zebble.net/docs/introduction-to-push-notifications

but I want to use local notification. 
how can I do it in Zebble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a local notification like this:

```
await Device.LocalNotification.Show("Title", "The message body!");
```

Comment: I need to set some notification with time and schedule !! 
like  Plugin LocalNotifications CrossLocalNotifications in Xamarin

Comment: @mj.84 Sorry I misunderstood your question, I updated my answer